# Why check TRANCOUNT before setting TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, snapshot-isolation

When using snapshot isolation, why do I often see IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 before setting the transaction level?

I.e., in a stored proc:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one reason is this from [Microsoft Documentations:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

A transaction cannot be set to SNAPSHOT isolation level that started with another isolation level; doing so will cause the transaction to abort. If a transaction starts in the SNAPSHOT isolation level, you can change it to another isolation level and then back to SNAPSHOT. A transaction starts the first time it accesses data.